# Why I cannot get equal upload and download speed on symmetrical channel?

Tags: http, sockets, ftp, networking, tcp

I'm assigned to a project where my code is supposed to perform uploads and downloads of some files on the same FTP or HTTP server simultaneously. The speed is measured and some conclusions are being made out of this.

Now, the problem is that on high-speed connections we're getting pretty much expected results in terms of throughput, but on slow connections (think *ideal* CDMA 1xRTT link) either download or upload wins at the expense of the opposite direction. I have a "higher body" who's convinced that CDMA 1xRTT connection is symmetric and thus we should be able to perform data transfer with equivalent speeds (~100 kbps in each direction) on this link.

My measurements show that without heavy tweaking the code in terms of buffer sizes and data link throttling it's not possible to have same speeds in forementioned conditions. I tried both my multithreaded code and also created a simple batch file that automates Windows' ftp.exe to perform data transfer -- same result.

So, the question is: is it really possible to perform data transfer on a slow symmetrical link with equivalent speeds? Is a "higher body" right in their expectations? If yes, do you have any suggestions on what should I do with my code in order to achieve such throughput?

PS.
I completely re-wrote the question, so it would be obvious it belongs to this site.

Comment: DUN, especially over cellular, are not symmetrical.  Does your provider gaurantee a certain bandwidth and throughput for your DUN?  If not, then you can't count on it.  Would be helpful to know if it's GPRS or 1xRTT...

Comment: Also, while this may relate to a program you are writing, it's essentially a network engineering question, and there are better places on the internet to get an answer...

Comment: This is 1xRTT connection, it's emulated and thus quality of the connection is guaranteed.

Comment: Adam, I'm looking for some theory.

Comment: Unless you give us the technology that forms the 'wire' between the two network points, we can't help you.  Is it CDMA, GSM, and which packet protocol on top of those networks are you using (lower than IP)?

Comment: But the reality is that network theory is still best answered by a network engineer.  I know enough about those technologies because I've dealt with them on a low level, so perhaps I can help you, but it's still not a programming problem, and there are still better places to go to find the answers..

Comment: OP: Despite the fact that you might be writing software that is related, the question is about networking, not programming.  Please don't email me to tell me to re-open the question, there are hundreds of other people here that can do that if so inclined.

Comment: Adam, this is standard CDMA 1x connection.

Comment: Robert, which are the chances that other moderators will actually look into the closed question?

"Thanks" for screwing my chance to get help on the real development issue.

Comment: Alex, you are the one doing a disservice to yourself by asking and expecting answers to a networking question on a programming question site.  There are plenty of resources focused on catering to your type of question and you would be better served by asking on one of them instead.

Comment: i would like to know the answer to this question. i don't care if it is answered by a network engineer or a duck posing as one. reopened.

Comment: I have the power to open it, and I agree with Robert that it should be closed.  I'm certain a number of moderators have seen it and agree.  It can still be voted up, though, and not a single other regular user thinks it should be more than 0.

Comment: Even Steven didn't upvote or favorite it...

Comment: @Steven, then you should do what the OP should have done and look for the answer some place where they talk about these things.  I wouldn't open a closed question about cars just because "I wanted to know the answer", that would be obnoxious because this site is about programming, not cars.

Comment: @Robert Gamble - I voted it up, even though it is a networking question. Reason - networking is very big. And most of the stuff will not be interesting to regular programmers. But stuff like this might be. I think it is ok to have some "pearls of programming bordering subjs" here.

Comment: Anyway not worth 3 down votes I think

Comment: @badbadboy, I have a car question that I am just itching to ask, cars are a big topic and although the question won't be interesting to most "regular programmers" it might be to some (those that program car computers for instance).  Can I count on an upvote from you if I decide to ask it here?

Comment: @badbadboy, if your answer is "no", what if I said that I was writing some software that cataloged car problems and solutions and I need the answer to my car question in order to complete my program so it is most certainly programming related.

Comment: @[Robert Gamble]: if you want to direct a comment to me you have to use my full name, otherwise it doesn't show up in the Responses tab. I saw your comment because I realized I was in such a hurry that i forgot to upvote this question and mark it as a favorite!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CDMA 1x consists of up to 15 channels of 9.6kbps traffic.  This results in a total throughput of 144kbps.

Two channels are used for command and control signals (talking to base stations, associating/disassociating, SMS traffic, ring signals, etc).

That leaves you with up to 124.8kbps.

--> Each channel is one way. <--

They are dynamically switched and allocated depending on the need.

Generally you'll get more download than upload because that's the typical cell phone modem usage.  But you'll never get more than 120kbps total aggregate bandwidth.

In practise, due to overhead of 1xRTT encoding, error correction, resends, etc, you'll typically experience between 60kbps and 90kbps even if you have all the channels possible.

This means that you can probably only get 30kbps-60kbps of upload and download simultaneously.

Further, due to switching the channels dynamically (and the fact that the base station controls this more than your modem - they need to manage base station channels carefully to keep channels free for voice calls) you'll lose time when it switches channels - it's not an instantaneous process.

So - 1xRTT can, in theory, give you 124kbps one way, but due to overhead, switching times, base station capacity, or the phone company simply limiting such connections for other reasons, you can't depend on a symmetrical link.

NOTE:

This will vary to some degree based on the provider and the modem.  For instance, some modems have 16 channels, and some providers support 16 channels.  In some cases those modems and providers work well together and can provide a full 144kbps aggregate raw bandwidth to the application, with only one dedicated channel (which has to work pretty hard) to deal with control, switching, and other issues.  Even then, though, with the overhead of the modem communications, then the overhead of PPP, then the overhead of IP, then the overhead of TCP, you're still looking at maybe 100-120kbps total bandwidth, both up and down.

Lastly, no provider yet supports transparent transfer of IP traffic.  In other words if you're modem is moving, the modem will switch to a new base station, but you'll completely drop the PPP session and have to restart it, as well as all the TCP sessions and such.  You typically won't get the same IP address, and so your TCP sessions will not recover gracefully.

The "fun" aspect to this twist is that this can happen even if you aren't moving.  If one base station gets loaded down, you may be transferred to another base station if you are close enough - there are other things that may make your modem transfer even without you moving.  So make sure you take this into account, since you seem to be keen on maintaining a full duplex, symmetric channel open.  It's tough to write stuff that will recover gracefully, nevermind anticipate it and do it quickly.  You would do well to work very closely with a modem manufacturer (such as Kyocera) on this - otherwise you won't get the documentation on how to control the modem chipset at the low level that you need.

-Adam

Comment: What would you say if I have a requirement from a higher body to have ~100kbps on each direction when I'm transferring both files simultaneously? ;)

Comment: I'd say the "higher body" will be disappointed. It’s not even theoretically possible (see Adam's answer). I agree (after years of testing on real 1x networks) that you're not going to get more than 60-90 kbps in practice.

Comment: You tell the "higher body" that you can't perform miracles.

Comment: I would tell them to invest in two modems, or EVDO.  An EVDO modem isn't that much more expensive than a 1xRTT, but the coverage isn't as good, so if you want great coverage and 200kbps of aggregate bandwidth, two 1xRTT modems are your best bet.

Comment: Well, it's not about what we can use, it's about what we have to use. We're using wide range of devices ranging from 1x to EV rev0 to EV revA.

Comment: Adam, thanks a lot!

If you curious, the app utilizes emulated environment, so there're ideal conditions. We're actualy able to see 135kbps of either down- or upload. Problems started when someone believed that they can have 135 kbps + 135 kbps when transmitting files in both directions at once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole drama with high equal speeds on both directions is because my higher body thinks that they have 144 kbps on uplink AND 144 kbps on DOWNLINK (== TWO pipes). Whereas in reality we have 144 kbps of ONE pipe which is switching directions when I transfer files.

Comment me if I right or wrong, please.